# Image swap based on refferer

Tags: jquery, src, referrer

I posted something similar, but realized my code needed to by in JQuery. I am trying to swap an image SRC if the referral URL contains facebook.com. The code I am using is swapping the image regardless of the referring URL. Im SUPER new to JS and JQ, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
if (!/facebook\.com/.test(document.referrer)) {
jQuery('#staffImage img').attr('src', 
'img1');
} else{
jQuery('#staffImage img').attr('src', 'img2.jpg');
}
```

Comment: test() is a method normally used for regex. 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Comment: Does it matter that anyone could spoof their Referrer header?

Comment: I would recommend using `var referrerHostName = new URL(document.referrer).hostname` to get the  actual hostname part of the referrer URL, and then use that for your `facebook.com` test. This will avoid potential issues where `facebook.com` might appear elsewhere in the URL besides the hostname.

Comment: Also, do you have `img1` already set as the image URL for the `img` element? (as in do you have it that way in the original HTML before the `referrer` code runs)? If so, why not just change the `src` only when that test returns true? Like `var referrerHostName = new URL(document.referrer).hostname;
if (/facebook\.com/.test(referrerHostName)) {
jQuery('#staffImage img').attr('src', 
'img2.jpg');
}` No point in setting the `src` for non-facebook referrer's if that's already set and should be considered the default, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook referrer is the exception, not the rule, right? So I would consider swapping those two condition blocks so that the `else` is what happens when it is the usual scenario, rather than having the `else` be for the unusual scenario. You also should only run your `test` against the hostname part of the referrer URL, which you can get by parsing the URL into a [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object. Also, one of your conditions has the `src` getting set to `img1` instead of `img1.jpg`, as pointed out by cngodles. This seems like an oversight, so let's assume you meant `img1.jpg`. Pulling it all together, the refactored code would look like:

```
try {
    var referrerHostName = new URL(document.referrer).hostname;
} catch {
    var referrerHostName = "";
}

if (/facebook\.com/.test(referrerHostName)) {
    jQuery('#staffImage img').attr('src', 'img2.jpg');
} else {
    jQuery('#staffImage img').attr('src', 'img1.jpg');
}
```

You should also take into consideration that `document.referrer` comes from the `Referrer` header, which means Referrer could be spoofed. It could also be empty under a lot of circumstances, including when browser's are configured not to send Referrer headers as an added privacy measure. For example, if you click on the `URL` link I provided above, and on that page, try `console.log(document.referrer)`, it will be an empty string, because SO automatically sets the attribute `rel="nofollow noreferrer"` on links provided in answers.

This is all to say that if you are wanting to provide something secure or confidential to certain requests, using the document.referrer is not a good way to do this. If, however, you just want a different user-experience that is fine to provide to non-facebook referrers just not what you had in mind, this is a perfectly good approach.

Answer (score 0):

The source in your example shows **img1** to be set to src, which would likely need to be **img1.jpg** or whatever the proper filename is.